# Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in F:\xampp\htdocs\application\models\mod_contactus.php on line 24

What is this error ? plase help me to figure out.

my model

```
function message_count(){

    $this->db->where('contactus_status', 'no');
    $num = $this->db->count_all_results('tbl_contactus');
    return $num->result();
}
```

controller

```
 function message_count()
{
    if($num = $this->mod_contactus->message_count())
    {
        $count['records'] = $num;
    }
    $this->load->view('admin/admin_messages',$count);

}
```

view

```
<?php if(isset($count)){echo $result;}?>
```

Comment: `$num` is not an object. Read some of the "Related" questions on right and figure out *why* it is not an object.

Comment: show full code. also view is not correct. according to your code it should be <?php if(isset($records)){echo $records;}?>

Comment: Why is marked as a duplicate?  The linked question is basically about debugging general errors, while this question is about a very specific error, in a specific framework, no less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$num = $this->db->count_all_results('tbl_contactus');
return $num->result();
```

As the function name implies, `count_all_results()` returns the count of table rows.
So `$num` is of type **integer**, therefore *not* an object so calling `$num->result()` is wrong (and pointless).

If you want the results, fetch them and count them *later*. Otherwise just return the count:

```
return $this->db->count_all_results('tbl_contactus');
```

Anyway, it's all in the manual, as I suggested in your previous question you should read it thoroughly before hacking code together. Or at least read it when you're stuck. Refernce for AR: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html. In this case:

> $this->db->count_all_results();
>
> Permits you to determine the number of
> rows in a particular Active Record query. Queries will accept Active
> Record restrictors such as where(), or_where(), like(), or_like(),
> etc.